# In how many ways can $7$ distinct balls be distributed to $4$ distinct boxes if three boxes receive two balls each and the other box receives one?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinations

> There are $7$ distinct balls and $4$ distinct boxes such that $3$
> boxes contain $2$ balls each and one box contains the remaining one
> ball. Find the number of ways of achieving this distribution.

My solution approach :-
$(^7C_2 \times4) \times (^5C_2 \times3) \times (^3C_2 \times2) \times (^1C_1 \times1) = 15120$

But the answer given is different from what I got. Can someone please let me know what I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You are ordering already ordered arrangements

Comment: So you could start with choosing a ball from seven and choose a box for the single ball. Rest of the six balls can be arranged in $\displaystyle {6 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2}~$ ways

Comment: @MathLover : I thought that as both the balls and boxes are distinct, that's why I first chose 2 balls out of 7 and then I have the option to put the two balls into any of the 4 boxes and similarly I continued with the other balls.

Comment: May be start with taking two boxes and four balls. How many arrangements with two balls in each box?

Comment: So there are 6 ways to choose 2 balls from 4 balls and I have got two options for the boxes. That means there are 12 ways, right?

Comment: No there are only $6$ distinct arrangements. When you select $2$ balls out of $4$ for the first box, you are left with two balls for the second box. As part of ${4 \choose 2}$, when you choose ball no. $1$ and $2$ for the first box, ball no. $3$ and $4$ are in the second box. But there is another selection as part of ${4 \choose 2}$ where you choose balls $3$ and $4$ for the first box. Then balls $1$ and $2$ go to the second box. So the selections are already ordered. Multiplying by $2$ will lead to duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Let's summarize the comments by Math Lover and the now deleted answer by true blue anil.

Suppose the boxes are lined up from left to right.  There are four ways to select the box which receives one ball, seven ways to select the ball that is placed in that box, $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select the balls that are placed in the leftmost open box, and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select the next open box, and one way to place the remaining two balls in the last open box.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$
distributions in which three boxes each receive two balls and the fourth box receives one ball.

Your answer is off by a factor of $6$ since you accounted for the $3!$ orders in which you could place two balls each in three of the boxes.  What matters is which box receives which balls, not the order in which the balls are placed.

Answer (score 0):

The multinomial coefficient can be defined as counting the number of ways of splitting a set of $n$ elements into an **ordered** sequence of $k$ disjoint subsets, each subset being $\;\geq 0$

For the given split of balls into boxes, the number of ways for
*one* such ordered sequence would be $\Large\binom{7}{2,2,2,1}$

But since the boxes are distinct, we need to permute the sequence in all possible ways, hence $\Large\binom{7}{2,2,2,1,}\frac{4!}{3!1!}$

Since the second term is equivalent to $\Large\binom{4}{3,1}$, we can as well represent it as $\Large\binom{7}{2,2,2,1}\binom{4}{3,1}$

To count placing distinct balls into distinct boxes as the product of two multinomial coefficients gives a mechanical way of solving such problems.

Comment: Three boxes contain two balls each.  You omitted a factor of $2$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Typo corrected

Comment: @trueblueanil : This is the grouping method formula and it gives the answer as 630 but this is not the correct answer.

Comment: I have revised my answer to give a simple mechanical way for such problems which may be of use to you in future.